# Column-wise decomposition of a matrix not working as intended using MPI

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I have an NxM matrix, with N=7 and M=8, like this:

```
[0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,
 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23,
24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31,
32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39,
40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47,
48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55]
```

It's coded into a 1d array of size NxM.

I want to perform a column-wise distribution among 3 processes, so that

Process 0 will have:

```
[ 0,  1,  2,
  8,  9, 10,
 16, 17, 18,
 24, 25, 26,
 32, 33, 34,
 40, 41, 42,
 48, 49, 50]
```

Process 1 will have:

```
[ 3,  4,  5,
 11, 12, 13,
 19, 20, 21,
 27, 28, 29,
 35, 36, 37,
 43, 44, 45,
 51, 52, 53]
```

Process 2 will have:

```
[ 6,  7,
 14, 15,
 22, 23,
 30, 31,
 38, 39,
 46, 47,
 54, 55]
```

Every process calculate its local N and M and the length of the local vector in this way:

```
int nloc = N;
int mloc = rank < M%nproc ? (M/nproc)+1 : M/nproc;
int *recv_vec = (int *)malloc(nloc*mloc*sizeof(int));
```

Note that `rank` is the rank of the process in the communicator it belongs. (I have 3 processes so it will be 0,1,2 respectively).

To perform the distribution I used `MPI_Scatterv` beacause I had to send a different number of columns to each process.
In order to do this I created a new datatype so that `MPI_Scatterv` could take the numbers at the right position and send it to the right process.

```
MPI_Datatype col, col_type;
MPI_Type_vector(nloc, 1, M, MPI_INT, &col);
MPI_Type_commit(&col);
//I resized the newly created vector so that MPI_Scatterv knows the right offset for the subsequent elements
MPI_Type_create_resized(col, 0, sizeof(int), &col_type);
MPI_Type_commit(&col_type);
```

At this point the distribution of the data can be done:

```
int sendcounts[]={3,3,2};
int displs[]={0,3,6};
MPI_Scatterv(matrix, sendcounts, displs, col_type, recv_vec, nloc*mloc, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

But what happen is that, since we sent columns

Process 0 receive this matrix (obviously in a 1d vector)

```
[ 0,  8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48,
  1,  9, 17, 25, 33, 41, 49,
  2, 10, 18, 26, 34, 42, 50]
```

and so on the other processes.

So I created, a receive type for the `MPI_Scatterv` too.

```
MPI_Datatype recv_row, recv_row_type;
MPI_Type_vector(mloc,1,nloc,MPI_INT, &recv_row);
MPI_Type_commit(&recv_row);
MPI_Type_create_resized(recv_row, 0, sizeof(int), &recv_row_type);
MPI_Type_commit(&recv_row_type);
```

And called `MPI_Scatterv` in this way:

```
MPI_Scatterv(matrix, sendcounts, displs, col_type, recv_vec, nloc, recv_row_type, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

What I expected to receive was what I said initially, but what the processes received is something like this:

```
Process 0: 0 24 48 17 41 10 34 8 32 1 25 49 18 42 16 40 9 33 2 26 50
Process 1: 3 27 51 20 44 13 37 11 35 4 28 52 21 45 19 43 12 36 5 29 53
Process 2: 6 22 38 54 15 31 47 14 30 46 7 23 39 55
```

There is something wrong with the `recv_row_type`, but i don't know what. Someone can help me?

This is the full code:

```
#define N 7
#define M 8

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int matrix[N*M];
    int menum, nproc, i, j;
    
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &menum);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nproc);
    
    //Matrix initialization
    if (menum == 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
                matrix[(i*M)+j] = i * M + j;
            }
        }
    }
    
    //Every process has its vector of size nloc*mloc
    int nloc = N;
    int mloc = menum < M%nproc ? (M/nproc)+1 : M/nproc;
    int *recv_vec = (int *)malloc(nloc*mloc*sizeof(int));
    
    //Create a custom datatype for a vector of nloc integers
    MPI_Datatype col, col_type, recv_row, recv_row_type;
    
    MPI_Type_vector(nloc, 1, M, MPI_INT, &col);
    MPI_Type_commit(&col);
    MPI_Type_create_resized(col, 0, sizeof(int), &col_type);
    MPI_Type_commit(&col_type);
    
    MPI_Type_vector(mloc,1,nloc,MPI_INT, &recv_row);
    MPI_Type_commit(&recv_row);
    MPI_Type_create_resized(recv_row, 0, sizeof(int), &recv_row_type);
    MPI_Type_commit(&recv_row_type);
    
    
    
    //Distributing data to other processes
    int sendcounts[]={3,3,2};
    int displs[]={0,3,6};
    MPI_Scatterv(matrix, sendcounts, displs, col_type, recv_vec, nloc, recv_row_type, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    
    
    //Printing data received by the process
    printf("Il processo %d: ",menum);
    for(i=0; i<nloc*mloc; i++){
        printf("%d ",recv_vec[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    
    //Freeing up memory and terminate MPI environment
    free(recv_vec);
    MPI_Type_free(&col);
    MPI_Type_free(&col_type);
    MPI_Type_free(&recv_row);
    MPI_Type_free(&recv_row_type);
    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and append the full code. Note you do not need to commit a type before resizing it since it will never be used in communications.

Comment: I appended the full code. The problem is in the receive type i used for the `MPI_Scatterv`

Comment: when creating the receive type, you need to swap `nloc` and `mloc`

Comment: A general note is that C doesn't apply any mathematical meaning to arrays. So you can allocate this as a C array corresponding to the higher layer matrix concept of either column-first or row-first. But efficiency-wise, the array should be accessed from lowest address to highest address. And that's the format which will suit MPI, cache memories and so on as well. So make sure you store them in the way that's most efficient for C/the computer, not necessarily the way that makes most sense mathematically.

Comment: Uhm, why? In the case of the first process, process 0 will send something like [0,8,16,24,32,40,48,1,9,17,25,33,41,45,2,10,18,26,34,42,50] and i want the receiving process to receive something like [0,1,2,8,9,10,16,17,18,...]. So shouldn't the stride be `nloc` and count be `mloc`in the receiving datatype? Why is it the other way?

Comment: each rank will receive `mloc` columns of the matrix, a column is always made of `nloc` integers. makes sense? if not, try sending `{1,1,1}` and receive `1` element and figure out by yourself what is wrong.

Comment: What I don't understand is that p0 is sending columns which are of length `nloc`, so every nloc element there is what should be the element of the row. So the first process will receive something like this `[0,8,16,24,32,40,48,1,9,17,25,33,41,45,2,10,18,26,34,42,50]`, is it right? If so my receiving process should take `0` then the `nloc-th`element then the `(2*nloc)-th` element, it means the count is `mloc` and stride is `nloc` so i'm creating this datatype `MPI_Type_vector(mloc,1,nloc,MPI_INT, &recv_row)`. What's wrong with this kind of thinking, i can't figure out

Comment: So it means that in `MPI_Scatterv` i will receive `nloc` amount of the defined receiving datatype `MPI_Type_vector(mloc,1,nloc,MPI_INT, &recv_row)`

Comment: On the receive end, data is read linearly (so to speak) and is written according to the receive datatype. In this case, on rank 0, the first received integer (0) goes to offset 0, and the second integer (8) goes to offset 3, the third integer (16) goes to offset 6 and so on. What you describe is the receiver writes linearly and picks the received data according to the receive datatype, and this is not how it works.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it, thank you!